# Receiving onesignal.com notifications

Tags: python, push-notification, onesignal

I would like my program to receive 3rd party notifications sent using the OneSignal (http://onesignal.com) platform.

Is there any (Python) client for it or is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneSignal push notifications work on Android, iOS, Amazon FireOS, and Windows Phone. There isn't a Python client side library as this isn't normally used for mobile app development.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Josh. I completely understand that this is not a common use case.

Comment: Josh, do you publish the notification API?

Comment: @RadekS Yes, see the REST API [Overview](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/server-api-overview) and [Add a device](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/players-add-a-device) docs.